# how can i throttle a stream of values added to a BehaviourSubject stream with next?

Tags: rxjs, throttling

Starting with an empty observable I have a steady stream of non-rxjs events that I need to throttle with rxjs but i cant find a way to create a throttled output. In my use case I do not know when the first value will arrive and nor can I determine the frequency of new values arriving.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-simpleexample-etebvz?file=index.ts

I was expecting this example to work and display the values added with next() to be throttled 1s apart but its not working.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, throttle } from 'rxjs/operators';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const example = subject.pipe(
  throttle(ev => interval(1000)),
  tap((ev) => console.log(ev))
)

example.subscribe();

example.next(2);
example.next(3);
example.next(4);
example.next(5);
example.next(6);
```

I cant find any online examples to match this (apparently) simple use case and working with rxjs feels unintuitive to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throttleTime` allows you to specify a number of milliseconds to wait before emitting again.

```
const example = subject.pipe(
  throttleTime(1000),
  tap((ev) => console.log(ev))
)
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-simpleexample-vjeqcw)

I recommend checking out the [operator decision tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree) and clicking through to see what options are available:

> I have one existing Observable
>
> I want to ignore values
>
> that occur too frequently

Comment: hi thank you for your answer. if i didn't mind losing items added with .next() is there a way to implement a similar solution with throttle()? I don't want to introduce artificial delays into the stream just level the output into regular intervals.

Comment: @LaurenceFass sorry, I thought you wanted a 1-second delay between emissions. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thank you for your help. questions answered. +1 for the decision tree hadnt seen that.